# WMI:monitor registry change

Tags: c++, wmi

In my project ,i want to monitor sofeware installation and unstallation in my system, so i use WMI event mechanism,but now i encounter a problem and have a question.

problem:

i want to monitor HKLM'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\unistall',but code[1] works error(ExecNotificationQueryAnsync failed with =0x80041058).while code[2] works ok,what's wrong?

[1]

```
hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
    _bstr_t("WQL"), 
    _bstr_t("SELECT * FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent WITHIN 1 " "WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'" "AND RootPath='software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\currentversion\\unistall'"
    ), 
    WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
    NULL,   
    pStubSink);
[2]

hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
    _bstr_t("WQL"), 
    _bstr_t("SELECT * FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent WITHIN 1 " "WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'" "AND RootPath='software'"
    ), 
    WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
    NULL,   
    pStubSink);
```

question：in My event consumer ,i want to get the software's name ,how can i do ?

thanks!!

Comment: your 'unistall' should be 'uninstall'

Comment: yeah i lost a 'n',but it still works error(ExecNotificationQueryAnsync failed with =0x80041058),i think it is '\' in the full path that can not be correctly recognized.

Comment: i find the answer to the problem ,it should change to RootPath='software\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\currentversion\\\\uninstall'

then somebody knows how to get the software's name ?thanks

Comment: when the event fires, capture and enumerate the values to capture "DisplayName". That's the golden nugget with the name of the un/installed software

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
SELECT * FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent WITHIN 1 " "WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'" "AND RootPath='software\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\currentversion\\\\unistall'"
```